# In oracle, how to find if a column contains any non-English letters?

Tags: oracle, unicode

I have got a requirement to print question mark if a field contain any foreign (non-English) letters. For instance, I need to achieve the following output.

[image]

I thought of using oracle [REGEXP_INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions114.htm#SQLRF06300) function, check if any foreign character exists & subsequently, use [CASE expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) to replace with question mark.

Unfortunately, I realized that oracle [REGEXP_INSTR doesn’t support Unicode characters](http://debugguru.blogspot.sg/2011/11/searching-unicode-characters-in-oracle.html). My intention was to use a REXEXP like “\p{L}^[A-Za-z]” but [\p{L}](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) doesn’t support with REGEXP_INSTR. Is there any other way that I can achieve this?

Below is some sample data:

```
select name from
(select '#Tag Company' name from dual union
select 'Company' name from dual union
select '中文' name from dual);
```

Comment: Try using convert function first and then regexp.

Comment: Thanks much Kaushik, when run CONVERT(name, 'US7ASCII', 'UTF8'), I see questions marks for foreign characters. Now it's just a matter of comparison.

Comment: You might want to look at the [TRANSLATE function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm)

Comment: Please don't put images in your question, copy/paste text.

Comment: Thank you for trying this. However I am just a learner here and no expert. Better to refer to expert's solution. I just commented from something I remembered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGEXP_xxx` functions supports unicode characters, example:

```
select regexp_replace('中文', '中', '文') from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('中文','中','文')
----------------------------
文文                          
1 row selected.
```

You may have a problem at `CONVERT` with certain European characters, for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT('ä é ô', 'US7ASCII') FROM dual;

CONVERT('ÄÉÔ','US7ASCII')
----------------------------
a e o                    
1 row selected.
```

You see, non-English characters (whatever that means) are not replaced by `?`.

If you ask to replace non-ASCII characters then I recommend this one:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('中文 aä eé oô', '[^ -~]', '?') FROM dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('中文AÄEÉOÔ','[^-~]','?')
--------------------------------------
?? a? e? o?                           
1 row selected.
```

or if you have to replace entire string by single question mark use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('中文 aä eé oô', '.*[^ -~]+.*', '?') FROM dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('中文AÄEÉOÔ','.*[^-~]+.*','?')
-----------------------------------------------
?                                         
1 row selected.
```

Maybe there is a much simpler solution. Set your environment variable

```
set NLS_LANG=.US7ASCII
```

then you client will automatically replace any non-ASCII character by `?`

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed answerer. This solution is much clear and accurate for many cases. However, CONVERT based solution is also work for my requirement that is to replace entire string with ? if it has non ASCII because it compair original & converted strings lateron.

Comment: When testing I realized that REGEXP '.*[^-~].*' filters ASCII too. Meaning select REGEXP_REPLACE('a1','.*[^-~].*','?') from dual; would return '?' which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the comment by Kaushik Nayak, I managed to resolve this problem as follows.

1. Convert character set with [CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) function.
2. Compare original and converted strings.

Here is the query.

```
select 
    name, 
    CONVERT(name, 'US7ASCII', 'UTF8') proc, 
    decode(name, CONVERT(name, 'US7ASCII', 'UTF8'), name, '?') name_proc from
(select '#Tag Company' name from dual union
select 'Company' name from dual union
select '中文' name from dual);
```

Output:

[image]